# Sql query how to get number of users group by city

Tags: sql, group-by

Imagine the following table Users

```
Users
------------------------

CITY        USERNAME        TOPIC 
city1        george          topic1
city1        george          topic2
city1        george          topic3
city1        chris           topic1
city1        chris           topic2
city2        john            topic1
city3        jenny           topic1
```

I want the following result group by city

```
city1 -> 2 users
city2 -> 1 user
city3 -> 1 user
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the distinct users for each city:

```
select city, count(distinct username) TotalUsers
from users
group by city;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78fca/4). The result is:

```
|  CITY | TOTALUSERS |
----------------------
| city1 |          2 |
| city2 |          1 |
| city3 |          1 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much bluefeet! I will accept it in a few minutes. Great work!